# Construction of tree using inorder and postorder traversal

Tags: discrete-mathematics, graph-theory, algorithms, trees

Consider the In-order and Post-order traversals of a tree as given below:

$\text{In-order: j e n k o p b f a c l g m d h i}$

$\text{Post-order: j n o p k e f b c l m g h i d a}$

The Pre-order traversal of the tree shall be:

1. $\text{ a b f e j k n o p c d g l m h i}$
2. $\text{ a b c d e f j k n o p g l m
           h i}$
3. $\text{ a b e j k n o p f c d g l m h i }$
4. $\text{j e n o p k f b c l m g
                   h i d a}$

---

My attempt:

We assume that given inorder and postorder traversal of binary tree. So, construction of binary tree using inorder and postorder traversal:

[image]

So, preorder is : $\text{a b e j k n p o f d g l c m i h}$, but none option is matched. Somewhere answer key is given option $(3)$.

> Can you explain it, please?

Comment: It appears to be an error in the answer key. I reconstruct the same tree and preorder that you do.

Comment: @BrianM.Scott, thanks for review. Please, answer this(as one line enough), so I can accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears to be an error in the answer key. I reconstruct the same tree and preorder that you do. I don’t even see any simple error, like a typo or a single small error in reconstructing the tree, that would explain the key’s answer.

Comment: @Mithlesh: You're welcome.